# ANSI_PADDING and Partition Switching

Tags: sql, sql-server, data-partitioning

I am in the process of migrating several on-premise SQL Server 2008R2 Enterprise Edition instances into AWS. The new SQL Servers are 2017 Enterprise Edition hosted on EC2 instances.

Currently, in our SQL Server 2008R2, some of the larger tables are partitioned (by date).  I have a partition management script that, on the first of every month, creates a new partition and switches out the oldest partition.  This works fine.  However, a lot of the columns in the partitioned tables have been created with ANSI_PADDING OFF.  When the partition management process runs, it creates a staging table, then iteratively adds new columns to the staging table, setting ANSI_PADDING dependent on the source tables column setting.  This staging table's subsequently used in the partition switch. Code snippet follows@

```
SELECT @AnsiPadding = is_ansi_padded FROM sys.columns WHERE object_id = object_id(@SourceTable) AND [name] = @columnname

    IF @AnsiPadding = 1
        BEGIN
        SET  @CreateTablestmt = 'SET ANSI_NULLS ON SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON SET ANSI_PADDING ON ALTER TABLE '+@Newtablename+ ' ADD [' + @columnname + ']  '+ @DatatypeFormat + ' ' + @nullvalue 
        PRINT @CreateTablestmt
        EXEC (@CreateTablestmt)                 
        END
        ELSE
        BEGIN
        SET  @CreateTablestmt = 'SET ANSI_PADDING OFF ALTER TABLE '+@Newtablename+ ' ADD [' + @columnname + ']  '+ @DatatypeFormat + ' ' + @nullvalue 
        PRINT @CreateTablestmt
        EXEC (@CreateTablestmt)
 END
```

I have just been testing this same procedure in SQL Server 2017 EE and it fails.

I receive the following error on creation of the Staging table:

```
Msg 50000, Level 16, State 1, Line 533
CONDITIONAL failed because the following SET options have incorrect settings: 'ANSI_PADDING'. 
Verify that SET options are correct for use with indexed views and/or indexes on 
computed columns and/or filtered indexes and/or query notifications 
and/or XML data type methods and/or spatial index operations.
```

Simple reproduction on Microsoft SQL Server 2017 (RTM-CU17) (KB4515579) - 14.0.3238.1 (X64)   Sep 13 2019 15:49:57   Copyright (C) 2017 Microsoft Corporation  Enterprise Edition (64-bit) on Windows Server 2016 Datacenter 10.0  (Build 14393: ) (Hypervisor)

```
SET ANSI_PADDING ON;
CREATE TABLE testANSI (col1 VARCHAR(15))
GO
SET ANSI_PADDING OFF;
ALTER TABLE testANSI ADD col2 VARCHAR(20)
```

yields:

```
Msg 1934, Level 16, State 1, Procedure DDLEventLogging, Line 13 [Batch Start Line 4]
SELECT failed because the following SET options have incorrect settings: 'ANSI_PADDING'.
```

The partitioned table has a multitude of data types in it; UNIQUEIDENTIFIER, SMALLINT, MONEY, CHAR, VARCHAR.

I can't change the definition of the staging table, as then the schema's don't match and I will get errors such as :

```
ALTER TABLE SWITCH statement failed because column 
'COLUMNA' does not have the same ANSI trimming semantics 
in tables 'DB.SCHEMA.MAINTABLE' and 'DB.SCHEMA.STAGINGTABLE'.
```

Rock and a hard place.

Other than creating a new table with ANSI_PADDING ON, and pumping all my data into it, do I have any other options?

Many thanks

Comment: Exactly when do you get the incorrect settings error? I would not expect that error when adding new columns to the staging table but maybe later when adding a filtered index, et. al. Make sure the session setting is set back to `ANSI_NULLS ON` after adding the columns for subsequent operations.

Comment: Hi @DanGuzman the error appears immediately on addition of the first column to have ANSI_PADDING OFF set against it.  I have updated by question with a quick example

Comment: I don't get an error with the code snippet you added. I suspect there's something else going on.

Comment: Hi @DanGuzman thanks for taking the time to look.  I have just now found a DDL trigger on the DB that's capturing eventdata. This is the cause of the error, not the script I posted.

Comment: You should be able to just add `SET ANSI_PADDING ON;` to the DDL trigger and be good to go. The setting will revert back to the session setting when the trigger completes.

Comment: Thanks for the tip.  I shall apply that update to the trigger

Answer (score 1):

Apologies.  Unknown to me, there's a DDL trigger on the database that's using EVENTDATA() to capture DDL events.  This is the source of the error, rather than the partition management script. 
As Dan suggested, I have added `SET ANSI_PADDING ON;` in the trigger and the partition maintenance job runs to completion.